# Rewrite if client accepts gzip compression

Tags: nginx, gzip, nginx-location

Is it possible to add a condition that the following rewrite only occurs if the HTTP request specifies the client accepts GZIP compression?

```
location ~* ^/names {
    rewrite /names/(.*)$ /cache/html/names/$1.html.gz last;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~* ^/names {
    if ( $http_accept_encoding ~ "gzip" )
    {
        rewrite /names/(.*)$ /cache/html/names/$1.html.gz last;
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

The if line checks whether the HTTP accept encoding header contains gzip (case insensitive).

If it doesn't it will rewrite the second rewrite rule.